# RMarkdown: Floating TOC and TOC at beginning

Tags: html, r, knitr, r-markdown

I was wondering if it is possible to have a floating table of contents and another one at the beginning of the document. My current front-matter looks like this:

````
---
title: "TEST"
author: brettljausn
date: January 15, 2018
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float:
      toc_collapsed: true
    toc_depth: 3
    number_sections: true
    theme: lumen
---


# Rest of the sample document: --------

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

I've tried adding another `toc: true`, but that just throws me an error message. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems possible but not obvious. Have you tried with Javascript?

Answer (score 12):

you just have to add true in front of toc_float:

```
---
title: "TEST"
output: 
  html_document:
  toc: true
  toc_float: true
  toc_collapsed: true
  toc_depth: 3
  number_sections: true
  theme: lumen
---
```

Also note that you have a comment within in your rmarkdown file, which will be interpreted as a header:

## Rest of the sample document: --------

Comment: The answer doesn't seem to work for me: There is only a floating toc, no toc at the beginning of the html.

Comment: Also you'd need to watch the indent in the yaml: toc_depth and number_sections needs to be indented. As well as everything after html_document (except theme) needs to be indented more.

Answer (score 10):

As pointed out by @j_5chneider in the comment of the top answer, the indentation is incorrect. Won't let me edit the given answer, so adding a new one to avoid confusion. Same answer that @Dan gave, but with indentation fixed.

```yaml
---
title: "TEST"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    toc_collapsed: true
    toc_depth: 3
    number_sections: true
    theme: lumen
---
```

Answer (score 0):

Concise version:

```
---
title: "TEST"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float:
      collapsed: true
    toc_depth: 3
    number_sections: true
    theme: lumen
---
```

See [Floating TOC](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#floating-toc) for reference.