# rmarkdown with page navigation on the side

Tags: r, r-markdown

Hi I would like to a add a page navigation on the side of my Rmarkdown file. It would be nice if it could look like the sidebar [on this page](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/rmarkdown_websites.html#site_navigation).

```
---
title: "My Title"
author: "My Name"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output: 
  html_document:
    theme: united
    highlight: tango
    code_folding: hide
    df_print: paged
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 2

---
# Section 1
abc
## Section 1.1
abcabc
# Section 2
abcabcabc
```

can anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you test [`toc_float: true`](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#floating-toc)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, to be honest: I searched the web and I tried a few things of which I was doubtful that they would work. And they didn't. toc_float: true works nicely :)

Answer (score 5):

I've tried this and works pretty well:

```
---
title: "TEST"
output: 
  html_document:
  toc: true
  toc_float: true
  toc_collapsed: true
toc_depth: 3
number_sections: true
theme: lumen
---
```

For more info please check the answer in this link: [RMarkdown: Floating TOC and TOC at beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261379/rmarkdown-floating-toc-and-toc-at-beginning)

Comment: Indentation is all wrong. For this to work you need to indent everything under `html_document:` to be indented the same way, and have them all nested under `html_document`. Added a new answer to clarify what I mean.

Comment: @Ricky Thank you Ricky, I've learnt and will do in that way in the future.

Comment: no problem, it is a very useful answer, but you should edit it to fix the indentation for people viewing this in the future. I tried suggesting the edit but it says `Suggested edit queue is full`.

Answer (score 4):

Adding one more answer which fixes the incorrect indentation on the answer given by @alika:

```yaml
---
title: "TEST"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    toc_collapsed: true
    toc_depth: 3
    number_sections: true
    theme: lumen
---
```